# Is there a downside to not be all Renegade or Paragon?

Tags: mass-effect

As in many games with moral choice, the best way (game wise) is to go all out on either. This often puts you in a situation where you turn out to be either Mother Teresa or Vlad the Impaler. Staying somewhere in the middle locks you out of either bonuses. But at the same time it makes for more interesting role playing.

I'm playing through ME1 now and I'm going the `Paragon` route. Playing a nice Shepard is mostly rewarding (and it's the way I like him) but ever so often, I get into a situation where I really would like to slap faces. But because of the Charm/Intimidate skills I still choose the Paragon option.

This is getting really annoying because while a Paragon Shepard is a nice person to play, he also seem to be pushed around by everyone and their mum - i.e. he's a complete wuss.

Can I still receive full Charm while mixing in a few Renegade points when I feel like it?

Comment: fwiw in me1 you can max both paragon and renegade with multiple playthroughs

Comment: In ME2 they did a great job with allowing paragon/renegade interrupts to alleviate that concern a bit.

Comment: @Shadur So that means I can be a generally nice guy that still has guts enough to not take crap from everyone?

Comment: Pretty much. You earn paragon/renegade points for taking the interrupt depending on which type it is. Also, there is one particular point in ME2 where *everyone* takes the Paragon Interrupt OR YOU HAVE NO SOUL.

Comment: When you hit ME2 - If you yourself are of a mixed Paragon/Renegade persuasion, you can edit your game file to give yourself a load of both points, so you never need worry about having enough to make the choice you want to take. I have personally played a mostly-Paragon game in 2 but there are certain Renegade options I will always, always take, because MAN are they satisfying. Even then, I was able to pass reputation checks. Also, Shadur is correct about that one interrupt. 

But yeah, ME1's talent page was... confusing sometimes.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As far as I know, maximum benefits for Paragon/Renegade are capped at 75%. So you can still get all benefits for being Paragon even if you take some Renegade points. The bonuses for each are as follows:

**Paragon:**

- 10% – Opens 2 Charm ranks. Gives 1 Charm point.
- 25% – Opens 2 Charm ranks. Gives 1 Charm point. Bonus: 10% shorter First Aid cooldown.
- 50% – No charm ranks/points. Bonus: 10% maximum health.
- 75% – Opens 2 Charm ranks. Gives 1 Charm point. Bonus: 5% reduction in cooldown on all powers.

**Renegade:**

- 10% – Opens 2 Intimidate ranks, gives 1 Intimidate point.
- 25% – Opens 2 Intimidate ranks, gives 1 Intimidate point, 10% reduction in weapon powers cooldown.
- 50% – 1 health regeneration per second.
- 75% – Achievement, opens 2 Intimidate ranks, gives 1 Intimidate point, 5% increase in damage/duration on all weapons and powers

Note that reaching 80% of either Paragon or Renegade grants an achievement. Having a high Paradon/Renegade score also grants a bonus when importing the character from Mass Effect to Mass Effect 2.